# If, g , h are functions such that f(n) = O(g(n)) and g(n) = O(h(n)) prove f(n) = O(h(n))

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I'm currently taking my first discrete math class and I'm having a bit of trouble. This is my first encounter with big Oh and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this particular problem.

I understand proofing that `n <= O(n)` because I can mathematically prove that there is such constant that will hold true for all values of n >= k

if `f`, `g` , `h` are functions such that `f(n) = O(g(n))` and `g(n) = O(h(n))`

use the definition of big oh given in class to prove that `f(n) = O(h(n))`

My answer was

`|f(n)| <= U1|g(n)| for all n >= k`

`|g(n)| <= U2|h(n)| for all n >= j`

thus

`|f(n)| <= U3|h(n)| for all n >= i`

Hence `f(x)` = `O(h(x))`

I tried to see the professor in her office hours but she said my proofing was incorrect, but would't really say why. I've spent so long on this I don't even know what to do. Any help would be great...

---

Okay! Let me try this again!

`|f(n)| <= U1|g(n)| for all n >= k`

`|g(n)| <= U2|h(n)| for all n >= j`

let `i` equal the largest of either `k ∨ j`.

let `U3` equal `U1 * U2`

`f(n) <= U3|h(n)| for all n >= i`

thus

`f(n) = O(h(n))`

Better?

Comment: You might have better luck at the [Math StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: this is not math.  this is basic algorithm with big O notation.  homework problem?

Comment: Yes, its a homework problem. And yes I know its a basic question. The answer is obvious but I don't know what a professor is looking for as far as wording/proofing

Comment: Well, what are `U3` and `i` supposed to be? Do they drop from the sky?

Comment: Try replacing `|g(n)|` in the first inequality with `U2|h(n)|` from the second inequality, then figure out what `U3` and `i` should be. That's your missing step.

Comment: btw, this property is called **Transitivity**.

Comment: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page60.html There you have a nice proof

Answer (score 3):

Using Big O definition:

```
f = O(g) iff exist c, n0 > 0 such that forall n >= n0 then 0 <= f(n) <= cg(n)

g = O(h) iff exist k, n1 > 0 such that forall n >= n1 then 0 <= g(n) <= kh(n)
```

Now take the last unequality and divide all members by `c`: `0 <= f(n)/c <= g(n)` and we can substitute `g(n)` in the second inequality: `0 <= f(n)/c <= kh(n)`. Finally multiply all members by `c` and you obtain `0 <= f(n) <= kch(n)` that is the definition of `f = O(h)`:

```
f = O(h) iff exist j, n2 > 0 such that forall n >= n2 then 0 <= f(n) <= jh(n)
```

In our case it is: `n2 = max(n0, n1)` and `j = ck`.

Comment: why must n2 be the maximum n0 and n1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use limits interpretation of Bachmann–Landau notations.

Then you can use the following reasoning:

[image: reasoning]

Comment: It seems they didn't define O using limits.

Comment: A limit of the quotient doesn't generally exist. `f \in O(g)` means `lim sup |f(x)/g(x)| < \infty`, so if you replaced your limits with `lim sup`, you'd get something.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes. Generally speaking of course you are right and we have to use supremum limit instead of limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute the second inequalty into the first you should end up with `U3 = U1 * U2`, but  what you called "i" is the crucial point. I think (but my theoretic days are far away in the past, so I could be wrong) that you could end up elegantly with a `n >= argmax{ k, j }`.

Answer (score 0):

Using another definition of Big O notation:

[image]

Sorry for the displaying, I could not do it how I wanted.